# LiveData is abstract android

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I tried initializing my LiveData object and it gives the error: "LiveData is abstract, It cannot be instantiated"

LiveData listLiveData = new LiveData<>();

Comment: How are you initializing your object? Please include your code so that we can see what's going on.

Comment: Um, that is because `LiveData` is `abstract`. What exactly are you attempting to do with `LiveData` here? You either need to create a subclass of `LiveData` or use `MutableLiveData`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it is abstract (as @CommonsWare says) you need to extend it to a subclass and then override the methods as required in the form:

```
public class LiveDataSubClass extends LiveData<Location> {

}
```

See [docs for more details](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata.html)

Answer (score 6):

In a ViewModel, you may want to use [`MutableLiveData`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/MutableLiveData) instead.

E.g.:

```
class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {
  private MutableLiveData<String> data = new MutableLiveData<>();

  public LiveData<String> getData() {
    return data;
  }

  public void loadData() {
    // Do some stuff to load the data... then
    data.setValue("new data"); // Or use data.postValue()
  }
}
```

Or, in Kotlin:

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
  private val _data = MutableLiveData<String>()
  val data: LiveData<String> = _data

  fun loadData() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
      val result = // ... execute some background tasks
      _data.value = result
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: don't you need to call loadData() inside getData(){}, right above "return data"?

Comment: Depends on your app. Probably you would want to call `loadData()` once but call `getData()` from several different places. The ViewModel could try to be smart about when to call `loadData()` or leave it up to the caller to choose when it's best to do that (e.g., user swipe to refresh).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you cannot instantiate it because it is an abstract class. You can try to use [MutableLiveData](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/MutableLiveData) if you want to set values in the live data object. You can also use [Mediator live data](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/MediatorLiveData) if you want to observe other livedata objects.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use MutableLiveData and then cast it to its parent class LiveData.

> public class MutableLiveData
>   extends LiveData
>
> [MutableLiveData is] LiveData which publicly exposes setValue(T) and postValue(T) method.

You could do something like this:

```
fun initializeLiveData(foo: String): LiveData<String> {
    return MutableLiveData<String>(foo)
}
```

So then you get:

```
Log.d("now it is LiveData", initializeLiveData("bar").value.toString())
// prints "D/now it is LiveData: bar"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think much better way of achieving this is by using, what we call is a [Backing Property](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-properties), to achieve better `Encapsulation` of properties.

Example of usage:

```
private val _userPoints = MutableLiveData<Int>()// used as a private member

val userPoints: LiveData<Int>
    get() {
        return _userPoints 
    } //used to access the value inside the UI controller (Fragment/Activity).
```

Doing so maintains an editable `MutableLiveData` private to `ViewModel` class while, the `read-only` version of it is maintained as a `LiveData`, with a `getter` that returns the original value.

P.S. - notice the naming convention for both fields, using an (_) **underscore**. This is not mandatory but advised.

Comment: Each time I see the `_` prefix for backing field, I wonder if `private val blah` + `fun blah()` will eventually become more popular.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Haa haa! Yeah you make a solid point there. There are so many notations these days. And sometimes reading a blog might just obscure your understanding of the language you are learning or already an expert of. Can only rely on Android official code samples and practices.

Comment: Oh man, I've seen enough bugs in enough Android official code samples that I'm not sure I'd say that out loud with such certainty - my favorite oddity was the Architecture Sample Todo-MVVM where they made a field/class mutable to make two-way binding work, but didn't update the docs and said "this is an immutable class..." also they don't use their own tooling like the SavedStateHandle. Iosched is so much more complex than the problem it's solving. Maybe it's just my opinion though, but I've written apps more complex with far less plumbing.